# FTP muliple files upload PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload files to FTP from PHP. It actually works, but not with multiple files. This is the code I have;

```
        for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++)
    {
        echo "<li>".$data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]."</li>";
        echo "<li>".$data['data']['metas'][$i]["file"]."</li>";
        echo "<li>".$data['data']['metas'][$i]["size2"]."</li>";
    }
```

This actually works. It will return the data for the files I uploaded, like this;

```
- FILENAME01.EXT
- upload/FILENAME01.EXT
- 198.96 KB
- FILENAME02.EXT
- upload/FILENAME01.EXT
- 93.77 KB
- FILENAME03.EXT
- upload/FILENAME03.EXT
- 94.59 KB
```

So far, so good. Now I'm adding the upload to FTP code, and this is what I have (directly under the code above);

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++)
    {
    $host = "ftp.domain.com";
    $username = "myuser";
    $password = "mupass";
    $local_file = $data['data']['metas'][$i]["file"];
    $remote_file = $data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"];

    $con = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die("Cant connect");
    $log = ftp_login($con, $username, $password) or die("Wrong credentials");

    ftp_pasv($con, true);

    $upload = ftp_put($con, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
    if($upload) echo 'ftp error';
    ftp_close($con);

    echo 'ftp success';
    exit;
    }
```

This will return "ftp errorftp success" on one line under the information about the files I uploaded. Only the first file that I uploaded will be uploaded to FTP, not all of them. I can't seem to figure out why. What am I missing here? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting echo of `ftp error` is the `$upload` variable will have a true value when first file is uploaded. and then you have exit at the end of the code that will stop the script to continue loop. Please remove the `exit;` and try. 
also see this reference. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158608/5650793)
Also please do not open and close the ftp connection within loop, make it close when the loop will complete and it uploads all the files to ftp.

Comment: Awesome tip! I've tried what you're saying here now, and now it all works perfectly. Thanks for the tip!